# Read Vagrantfile programmatically with Ruby

Tags: ruby, vagrant

Is there any way to read the Vagrantfiles with ruby natively, without having to read the content of the file and then parse for parts of the configuration that I need?

The idea is to read for a required parameter of the Vagrantfile, and use the piece of information elsewhere, I tried to include the Vagrantfile, since it is a ruby file, but I believe the file is just executed and a guest OS will be started, and my script will be blocked until vagrant returns the control back to my script.

Comment: The contained content *is* in fact Ruby code so instead of parsing you should execute them - but be beware of the security implications! Since Vagrant already does this, maybe look into their [codebase](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant).

Answer (score 0):

Like cmur2 said.

Be particularly wary since the vagrant environment can overwrite the Vagrantfile in the host environment.  It gets mounted read-write.